# How to manage the log file size on secondary replica (log backups)?

Tags: availability-groups, transaction-log, sql-server-2019

I am learning about SQL AG.

Currently we have 1 SQL server and we run weekly full and hourly log backups.

The log backups truncate the log and prevent from filling up the disk.

When I configure an AG between 2 servers (in sync or async mode), then log backups on primary will take care of truncating log file on primary. This is same behaviour as with single instance sql server.

On the secondary node, do I need to also setup log backups to prevent log file growth (filling up the disk)? Or does AG technology automatically sync handle log size when log backup is done on primary node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Or does AG technology automatically sync handle log size when log backup is done on primary node?

Log backups taken on any node will move the truncation lsn forward and be reported back. Thus, you do not need to take log backups on all nodes, just one, and the truncations will still occur.